# Caixa de texto responsiva

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout-responsivo, redimensionamento

Tenho uma caixa de texto em cima de um image-map que é responsivo, dessa forma:

```
<div class="lala" role="main" style="height:100%">
<img class="imgg" src="../images/sellec.jpg" style="opacity:0; width:1790px; height:974px" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">

<area target="" alt="Tubeteira" title="Tubeteira" href="tub_oee.php" coords="290,250,140" shape="circle">
<area target="" alt="Rebobinadeira" title="Rebobinadeira" href="reb_oee.php" coords="715,250,130" shape="circle">
<area target="" alt="Cortadeira" title="Cortadeira" href="cort_oee.php" coords="1100,250,130" shape="circle">
<area target="" alt="CMW" title="CMW" href="empac_oee.php" coords="1510,250,130" shape="circle">
<area target="" alt="PW30" title="PW30" href="pw30_oee.php" coords="300,580,130" shape="circle">
<area target="" alt="S15" title="S15" href="s15_oee.php" coords="720,580,130" shape="circle">
<area target="" alt="IN3AL" title="IN3AL" href="in3al_oee.php" coords="1100,580,130" shape="circle">
<area target="" alt="Geral" title="Geral" href="geral_oee.php" coords="1480,580,130" shape="circle">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<input id="enter"type="text" class="heye"name ="tempo">  
</map>
</div>   
<script > $('map').imageMapResize();</script>
```

No CSS do input há isso:

```
.heye {
position: absolute;
top:840px;
left: 1530px;
   }
```

Já tentei usar esses valores em %. mas ainda assim não deu certo. Sempre que a resolução de tela muda, o image-map redimensiona corretamente, mas o mesmo não acontece com o input text. O que pode ser feito para que o mesmo também redimensione?
Abaixo está um print de como fica normalmente o image-map com o input text:
[image: Meu print]

Comment: Como assim, como vc quer que o input redimensione? Vc não quer ter barras de scroll na telas? Como vc quer o comportamento desse input?

Comment: Gostaria que ele permanecesse no mesmo ponto da imagem quando essa diminuísse ou aumentasse.

Comment: Vendo a imagem ficou mais fácil de entender. Tente editar a pergunta e colocar o CSS/HTML completo do que vc tem até o momento que fica mais fácil. Além disso, não sei se vc sabe, mas esse layout poderia ter sido feito completamente com CSS, não precisava fazer o imagem-map para isso, não faz sentido...